# ng-controller não é encontrado (não funciona corretamente)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tenho um modal que possui um controller "userCtrl". Eu chamo todos os scripts no carregamento da página (final do body), porém, os modais, eu carrego dinamicamente a partir do momento que o usuário clicar no botão, usando a função `$.get()` eu carrego o modal e faço um `$(#modal).modal('show')`.

O problema é que, o ng-controller que está contido no modal que é carregado quando o usuário clica não funciona, é como se o controller não funcionasse, não executa nada que esteja dentro desse controller no modal, como se ele não fosse encontrado.

- Por que isso pode ocorrer?
- Tem alguma maneira de consertar isso?
- Gostaria de saber se isso ocorre porque o script do controller é carregado antes do elemento que contém o ng-controller.

Função que carregar o html do modal onde está incluso o `ng-controller`

```
showModal = function(id, path) {
    $.get(path, response => {
        $(".modals").append(response);
        $(id).modal('show');
        $(id).on("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
            $(id).remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Trecho do modal

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdCreateGrupos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" ng-controller="gruposCtrl" ng-init="init()">
```

Trecho do controller

```
app.controller("gruposCtrl", function($scope, $gruposService, $compile) {
$('#mdCreateGrupo').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    $(".alert").remove();
    $("#textGrupo").val("");
});

$scope.init  = function() {
    console.log('inicio');
}
```

Tudo estava funcionando corretamente até eu usar a função $.get, antes eu estava usando o ng-include, porém estava muito verboso porque era um ng-include para cada modal, agora eu fiz essa função que funciona para qualquer modal.

Comment: Existem várias possibilidades. Incluir um trecho do código pertinente pode aumentar suas chances de receber uma resposta que resolva seu problema.

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após ler esse issue no github: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1307 

 O usuário **ceymard** citou que

> From what I understood in the end, the behavior of transclude is perfectly normal in that it creates its creates a new scope. So does ng-controller, which results in having them each have a distinct scope and thus not be able to interact together.

O que eu pensei em fazer então foi que toda vez que eu chamar um modal, eu usasse o $compile mandando o $scope para o response, feito isso, o código para abrir o modal ficou assim:

```
showModal = function(id, path) {
    $.get(path, response => {
        $(".modals").append($compile(response)($scope));
        $(id).modal('show');
        $(id).on("hidden.bs.modal", () => {
            $(id).remove();
        });
    });
}
```

Ou seja, toda vez q eu chamo o modal, eu compilo o response mandando o `$scope` fazendo-o funcionar corretamente.